# Is it possible to write formatted output directly to a HANDLE on Windows?

Tags: windows

My current hacky workaround is to duplicate a file descriptor handle with `DuplicateHandle`, open a file descriptor using `_open_osfhandle`, open a `FILE*` with `_fdopen`, use `vfprintf` and then `fclose` the file. Obviously, this is not great. I do known that it is possible to use functionality in `conio.h` to output directly to the current console but unfortunately that doesn't work for my needs.

Comment: You could `sprintf` to a string and `WriteFile` that. If you need to work with actual C files, your method is probably the shortest safe way to do it.

Comment: Okay, I was hoping for a way that could work in low memory conditions or that doesn't use the heap but that is probably good enough.

Comment: Low memory conditions? If formatting a single string before you push it off to a kernel buffer somewhere is a burden on memory, you've got much bigger issues... The only way to avoid allocating memory in this case is if you wrote to the handle byte for byte, which is massively inefficient. Relax and let the memory flow through you; there's still time to optimize the allocations that matter later.

Comment: False, it is possible to take advantage of heap memory if it is available and then fall back to a slower method if not. An example of where this is important is if some mission critical data must be logged regardless of heap conditions.